# update nested array object if exists yq

Tags: yq

Having the following YAML how to using jq

```
versions:
  - name: test1
    version: "0.0.1"
  - name: test2
    id: "1"
```

How to update a version by its name fullfilling the following scenarios:

adding a a new object with a new name:

- name: test3
  version: "0.0.3"

updating an existing object with a new version:

- name: test1
  version: "0.1.1"

updating an existing object with no version:

- name: test2
  version: "0.0.2"

I have tested the following command, but i get undesired results like when replacing the version it keeps the old version and not the new one

```
yq -i ".versions= (.versions +  {"name": "test", "version": "0.0.5"} | unique_by(.name))" test.yaml
```

Comment: So your asking 3 different things? Please limit to 1... Also 'but I get undesired results' maybe show us what you're seeing, and what you're expecting.

Comment: its 1 command that fullfils the 3 scenarios, no 3 different things, updated the undesired results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you care about the array's ordering (which I believe you do), the general answer would be: Find the matching index or default to a new one past the last, and add both fields to the item (or null) behind that index.

You didn't specify [which implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info) of `yq` you are using. While the solutions are similar, they are certainly not identical.

This would be a solution using [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq):

```bash
yq='(.versions | .[(to_entries[] | select(.value.name == $name).key) // length]) += {$name, $version}'

# Adding a new object with a new name
yq -y --arg name test3 --arg version 0.0.3 "$yq"

versions:
  - name: test1
    version: 0.0.1
  - name: test2
    id: '1'
  - name: test3
    version: 0.0.3

# Updating an existing object with a new version:
yq -y --arg name test1 --arg version 0.1.1 "$yq"

versions:
  - name: test1
    version: 0.1.1
  - name: test2
    id: '1'

# Updating an existing object with no version:
yq -y --arg name test2 --arg version 0.0.2 "$yq"

versions:
  - name: test1
    version: 0.0.1
  - name: test2
    id: '1'
    version: 0.0.2
```

Using [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), this can be translated to:

```bash
yq='(.versions | .[(to_entries | .[] | select(.value.name == env(name)).key) // length]) += {"name": env(name), "version": env(version)}'

# Adding a new object with a new name
name=test3 version=0.0.3 yq "$yq"

versions:
  - name: test1
    version: "0.0.1"
  - name: test2
    id: "1"
  - name: test3
    version: 0.0.3

# Updating an existing object with a new version:
name=test1 version=0.1.1 yq "$yq"

versions:
  - name: test1
    version: 0.1.1
  - name: test2
    id: "1"

# Updating an existing object with no version:
name=test2 version=0.0.2 yq "$yq"

versions:
  - name: test1
    version: "0.0.1"
  - name: test2
    id: "1"
    version: 0.0.2
```